# Linking Flutter app to an opencart eCommerce webstore

Tags: flutter, dart, opencart, e-commerce

My customer had bought an Opencart website and an eCommerce Flutter app (from inspireUI/Fluxstore).
And my job is to implement the payment part into the app, (the app now loads the payment page from the website into a WebView and sync all the data the user had entered).

The user has to complete the web form, adding his credit card and complete the payment process.

Anyone have some documentations or any previous experience to help?
I've searched and contacted inspireUI support team and did not find helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

There is not any documentation like this. You need to track all code and catch what happens.

By the way, you have to be careful while using WebView. There are some annoying issues related to payment like fraud detection and related to AppStore processes. You can read [more](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60687).